# Failed to add image

Tags: magento2

I am not able to add image to magento with the following error.

> Can't create directory /home/ccc/public_html/shop/var/generation/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/Indexer/Product/ProductRuleIndexer/.

I am able to save product details data but not the picture. Could anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no write rights (sorry for the tongue twister) on the `var/generation` folder or a subfolder.
I usually solve this by running in the command line, in the magento root folder this:  `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .`

Comment: my server dont allow me to run the command. I have granted the permission to all app, pub and var folder to have 775 permission. I checked again on the var/generation folder is having the 775 too. Do i need to set to 777?

Comment: don't set 777. Make sure the `var/generation` folder has 775 recursively.

Comment: i use Filezilla to do that. In progress now. By the way, is that safe to have 775 permission for all 3 folders app, pub and var ?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Issue is still the same. I have used the Filezilla to do the 775 with recursive for folder var/generation. But the error is still showing

Comment: I dont have command-line access to my shared hosting server.

Comment: For permissions on shared hosting, see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: I noticed most of the solutions given requires me to run the command in my shared hosting server. The problem here is my server dont permit me to run any command. IS there any other alternative?

Comment: If you're not allowed to run commands you may be in trouble. Magento 2 relies heavily on running commands.

Comment: @Marius, thanks. i have been thinking to leave Magento. But i want to get final clarification. If i setup my project in localhost and fix all issues using the command lines. WIll i still require to use any command lines once i move to PROD?

Comment: from time to time you might need it. To index stuff, to set the maintaince flag, to install extensions via composer and others.

Comment: Thanks Marius, you have been very helpful. I am leaving Magento ~~

Answer (score 0):

run

```
chmod -R 777 /home/ccc/public_html/shop
```

Comment: won't this create any security issue by granting 777?

Comment: Yes. Giving the whole Magento directory 777 permissions is the slegde hammer solution to permission related problems, it's effective, but also can do damage. What's important is that the `var` directory is writable by the web server. If it belongs to the web server group, `chmod -R 770 /home/ccc/public_html/shop/var` suffices.